# Stop reusing PHP_VALUE for different sites with PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php.ini

I noticed the following behavior or PHP-FPM:

Take a look at these two Nginx configs:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    example.com;
    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/www/i.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "display_errors=1";
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
server { 
    listen         80;
    server_name    example.net;
    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/www/i.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

and `/srv/www/i.php` file:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

As you can see the only difference is `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "display_errors=1";`.

Now if you kill all FPM workers, and open `example.net` first, you will see `display_errors` is `Off` as expected. And at `example.com` you will see `display_errors` is `On`.

But if you visit `example.net` again **and** this request is proceeded by the same worker, you will get `display_errors` as `On`.

All FPM workers are working in the same pool.

**Question:** how to make `example.net` always work with default settings?

**Possible solutions:**

- Define `PHP_VALUE` with the desired settings in `example.net` config as well.
- Seems to be a "right" solution - create separate pools of workers for each site.

But we have a lot of websites on our server, and both solutions mean a lot of routine work to set up. I was wondering if there is an easier way.

**Update:**

`display_errors` setting in my example was chosen just to demonstrate the problem. The same situation takes place with any `php.ini` setting. As per comments, it is a bad idea to mix production and development sites on a single server.

Comment: Another option is to put your non-production sites on an entirely different server.

Comment: Side note: As of PHP 5.2.4 [display_error](http://php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) expects a string value and should be set to either `stdout` (default) or `stderr`.

Comment: @Daniel I will keep it in mind, thanks) This directive was chosen for example. In the real life I faced this problem when I set `error_log=/some/file.txt` for the only site and noticed that there were errors of other sites there as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason this happens is most likely that "PHP settings passed with php_value or php_flag will overwrite their previous value", as described [PHP-FPM documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php).

I assume that in your PHP configuration `display_errors` is disabled. Then you visit the .net-page, in which your `phpinfo()` confirms that it is disabled.

Then you visit the .com-page and Nginx passes `display_errors=1` to your PHP-FPM worker in that same pool. That overwrites the previous value of `0` with the new value `1`. You can confirm that with `phpinfo()`.

Now the PHP-FPM pool settings is set to `display_errors=1`.

When you visit the .net-page again, `phpinfo()` indeed confirms that `display_errors=1` because it was overwritten when Nginx passed the value of `1` to the same pool that now handles another of your websites.

The solution is either to move development to another server, as suggested in the comments. Or to create a dedicated PHP-FPM pool for your site, which is the least you should do.

Bonus:

And please don't do this in your Nginx configuration: `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "display_errors=1";`

That ought to be in the php configuration file, preferably in the site's own fpm pool configuration.

> But we have a lot of websites on our server, and both solutions mean a lot of routine work to set up. I was wondering if there is an easier way.

You can use the per pool prefix for a quick fix. In any case, putting multiple sites on a single worker pool is a bad idea because I only need to get one of your sites to execute a malicious php script of mine to compromise ALL other sites that use the same worker, without any effort.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I have to revise my approach of using PHP-FPM